# How to use dynamicLinkDomain including path with FirebaseAuth Email Link?

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I am setting ActionCodeSettings parameters as:

```
url = URL(string: "https://customDomainName/auth/app")
dynamicLinkDomain = "customDomainName/flink"
```

but when requesting signinLink in ios app it shows error: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17074 "The Firebase Dynamic Link domain used is either not configured or is unauthorized for the current project."

I also setup FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains in Info.plist with https://customDomainName/flink.
It only works when I set dynamicLinkDomain="customDomainName" but I don't want to use root path of my domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in this case is that https://customDomainName/flink isn't a valid domain (i.e. it represents a URL rather than a domain name).

For the `dynamicLinkDomain` parameter, a valid domain name is needed. If you don't want to use the root customDomainName for your links, you can create and use a subdomain like `links.customDomainName.com` or similar.

Hope that helps!

Comment: ofc, it's not Domain name, that's why I wrote I want to use full paths. Why Dynamic Links support paths, but Auth Link cannot be controlled.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains.